# Association bonus: is 90=100?

Tags: bug, reputation

Having associated my Math.SE account to meta.SO (to post [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/180850/222728)), I got the association bonus +100 on both sites. The `reputation` tab in my profile confirms this. But the drop-down activity summary, shown when hovering over my user name, says it's +90.

[image: bonus]

Looks like a bug. I thought of posting this on meta.SO, but there the amount is shown as +100 in both places. Could be a Math.SE-specific bug for all I know.

---

Clarification: "drop-down activity summary" with +90 is shown when hovering over my user name here:

[image: username]

I am unaware of a more official name for it.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "the drop-down activity summary, shown when hovering over my user name". I've tried hovering over every occurrence of your user name I could find, and see no such drop-down. Could you describe in more detail what you are doing to produce it, and/or give a more complete screenshot?

Comment: @ZevChonoles Done. The activity summary is shown when *I* hover my user name. I don't think you would be able to reproduce the error without being an SE developer.

Comment: Ah, yes, that drop-down; I should have remembered :) I'm pretty sure you're right, that's only visible to you and the SE team.

Comment: Hooray! We found a contradiction in mathematics. Now we can all go home! :-)

Comment: @Asaf, strictly speaking, doesn't the contradiction just occur in systems strong enough to do counting?

Comment: @AsafKaragila I am already at home, since it is a weekend.

Comment: @Gerry: Strictly speaking? Yes. But one can label it as heuristics implementations of some algorithm and conclude that the contradiction must be in the mathematics. I'm trying to be a bit comp. sci. here... :-)

Comment: @user17762: Then you'll have to go outside, then you can come back home.